# Why when I render Django template on ajax, success does not appear on the browser?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My Html page isn't rendered on ajax success when I use `console.log()` in the js file, the HTML page is printed out in the browser console but not in the browser itself.

kindly check my following code:

views.py:

```
def Filter_by_Products(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            print("filter by function!")
            filter_brand = request.GET.get('filter_brand')
            products_qs, qs_color, qs_size = product.objects.Filter_brand(filter_brand.rstrip(','))
           context={
            "object_list": products_qs,
            'colors': qs_color,
            'sizes':qs_size
            }
            # print(products_qs)
            # print(qs_color)
            # print(qs_size)

     return render(request,"product/products.html",context)
```

ajax.js:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'/cart/api/filterby/',
        method:'get',
        data:
            {
                'filter_brand':str,

            },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            // location.reload()
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    })
```

After googling on my question, I found that my problem is that I'm trying to mix the server side with the client side and the solution is to send my HTML template using HttpResponse not render function and then by using javascript, I select the HTML page and change content with the new html.

Actually, I didn't understand clearly the problem and why mixing server with client caused that problem and why my code wasn't working from the first time using render, so could you please explain more in details or refer links to me to understand.

also, I'm familiar with Django celery and Redis, if i can use those technologies in that situation, could you just refer to me how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

When i'm working with Django and Ajax, i like to use JsonResponse, a library from django.http. This way, I can pass the status response (200, 500, ...), and the data that will be treated in front.

The problem in your case, is that after you received the response, you are reloading the page.

```
// location.reload()
```

As your responde data is an object, you have to define, using javascript, where it will be placed on the screen, for example:

```
success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#div_object_list").html(data.object_list);
    },
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i know that i should use JsonResponse but i don't know why this issue is happening when i mix server-side  with client-side

Comment: Can i use django celery and redis in this case ?

Comment: You will want to get the celery task return?

Answer (score 0):

No problem in `return render(request,"product/products.html",context)`, it will return a rendered html page's content.

The problem is in your ajax request calling: `// location.reload()`, referring to [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)  it reloads current page only without replacing page's content with returned response.

If you need to replace the entire page with returned response, so your ajax `success` function should like:

```
success: function (response) {
        var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
        newDoc.write(response);
        newDoc.close();
       }
```

If you just need to replace with specific html div, you can do:

```
success: function(response) {
            $('#my-div').html(response);
        }
```